# unable to ssh into local qemu instance via port forward

Tags: qemu, ubuntu-18.04, packer

I am trying to build a custom Ubuntu (ISO built from `bionic - 18.04.2`) qcow2 image via `packer`. This fails in the step where `packer` tries to SSH to the instance via port forward.
I can see from VNC that the instance spins up fine, and I can login with the given ID manually on the *console*, but `packer` is unable to ssh.

I tried to ssh, `ssh` form host gets stuck for a long time and errors out:

```
ssh -vvv -p 2226 admin@127.0.0.1
debug1: identity file /home/ani/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
```

Though the port is up:

```
$ sudo lsof -i:2226
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
qemu-syst 31185 root   14u  IPv4 50059412      0t0  TCP *:2226 (LISTEN)
```

SSH server is running in the instance, and the user is a valid one. What else do I need to check to ensure SSH can happen via the host ?
On the same host, I am able to make Ubuntu Trusty (`14.04`) qcow2. So, I am not sure if some additional qemu command line arguments need to be passed (for port forwarding to work correctly) 
Or some `sshd` configs need to be changed on Ubuntu bionic (`18.04`)!

This is the qemu command line:

`/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -smp 4 -m 8192M -boot once=d -name ubuntu-bionic-custom-0.1.qcow2 -drive file=output/ubuntu-bionic-custom-0.1.qcow2,if=virtio,cache=writeback,discard=ignore,format=qcow2 -serial file:serial.out -device e1000,netdev=user.0 -machine type=pc,accel=kvm -netdev user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::2226-:22 -cdrom /home/ani/ubuntu-bionic-custom-0.1.iso -vnc 127.0.0.1:83`

version:

```
$ /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version 
QEMU emulator version 2.11.1(Debian 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.4)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

--EDIT--

```
$ route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.192.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
10.192.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

$ ip netns ls 
$
```

Comment: is the vm connecting to a bridge or virtual switch?

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin How do I find that out!? I am using `packer` and I am using similar configurations which used to work for `ubuntu trusty (14.04)`

Comment: Have you checked iptables/ufw rules in the vm?

Comment: @hardillb I tried with `sudo ufw disable` and still same!

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in the arguments that packer is passing qemu ? or can I change something and try ? this does not seem to be the SSH (in guest) issue.

Comment: can you update the question with the output of `route -n` and `ip netns ls`

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin added the command outputs

Comment: so your network interfaces are bridged, you have 3 different ones, I have never used packer,  but I would try to get the actual IP address of the VM by using bridge control commands [link][https://linux.die.net/man/8/brctl] and try using the `ssh -g` flag for port forwarding

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin ok, that would be a manual thing, I want to automate the process of creating `qcow2` from ISO using `packer`, so `packer` should be configured to send the right arguments to `qemu` - I don't know what I am missing here!

Comment: yes, it is an automation tool, but you have some underlying network issue probably related to the number of bridged interfaces you have a NAT'd bridge with DHCP `virbr0` you have a VM to VM only bridge `br0` and you have a bridge for containers `lxbr0` you are doing ssh >> localhost >> port forward >> VM - this should work fine so long as your actual host network can reach the network your VM is on - try getting the real IP address from the VNC session and see can you ping it, you have a low level networking issue

Comment: ok, let me check that

Answer (score 0):

This happened to be an issue with the bionic ISO image that I was using. I had changed it to use traditional networking (also falling back to older iface naming scheme), instead of NetPlan. But with that, I had to add an entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` for `eth0`